# Intellij resource not found from Gradle Project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, resources

I'm having a library (which is built with Gradle 7.4) with a structure like this:

```
|
|- src
| -  main
| - - java
| - - resources
```

In this library, I have a class which loads a resource file like this:

```
var resource=this.getClass().getResource("sample.properties");
```

My sample.properties file is placed under src/main/resources

When building the library, Gradle is placing the compiled classes under build/classes/java/main and resources under build/resources/main.

Now, I have a Application, which is a non-Gradle project and has a module dependency to my Library.
My Application uses the Library, which then loads the resource file.
Now, when I run my Application, the debugger states that it looks for the resource file under build/classes/java/main/mypackage/sample.properties.

But, as stated before, the resource is under build/resources/main.
The resource afterwards is null.
**My Question:** How can my Library load my resource file accordingly?

**Update 24.11:** I forgot to mention that this worked with Eclipse (because it copies classes and resources to the same dir) but not with Intellij and now I'm trying to fix this with Intellij IDEA.

Comment: You best option would be to set up the complete application to use Gradle and configure dependencies using Gradle as project dependencies. Since build the library module by Gradle but build and run the application not using Gradle - it uses different paths for resources.

Answer (score 0):

If the parent application which uses your library (which requires some resource files) is a non-gradle/non-maven project being built/compiled/run using plain java commands.

You can try to supply the resource folder externally as a classpath (using `-cp` option) in the `java` commands

```bash
java -cp /path/to/resource application.jar
```

Another option would be to ask for the resource file explicitly in the library APIs (methods, class constructors etc.) which needed to be supplied by the user of the library (parent application). This will eliminate runtime crashes on missing files at a pre-defined path.

Comment: Actually I want to achieve this using Intellij IDEA, and in the run configuration I could manually add the path to the resource to CP, but then I'm not able to share with others bc it's stored as an absolute Path :(